# Regex: ignore characters that follow

Tags: regex

I'd like to know how can I ignore characters that *follows* a particular pattern in a Regex.
I tried with positive lookaheads but they do not work as they preserves those character for other matches, while I want them to be just... discarded.

For example, a part of my regex is: `(?<DoubleQ>\"\".*?\"\")|(?<SingleQ>\".*?\")`
in order to match some "key-parts" of this string:

```
This is a ""sample text"" just for "testing purposes": not to be used anywhere else.
```

I want to capture the entire `""sample text""`, but then I want to "extract" only `sample text` and the same with `testing purposes`. That is, I want the group to match to be `""sample text""`, but then I want the full match to be `sample text`. I partially achieved that with the use of the `\K` option:

```
(?<DoubleQ>\"\"\K.*?\"\")|(?<SingleQ>\"\K.*?\")
```

Which ignores the first `""` (or `"`) from the full match but takes it into account when matching the group. How can I ignore the following `""` (`"`)?

Note: positive lookahead does not work: it does not *ignore* characters from the following matches, it just does not include them in the current match.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is there an automatic downvote bot or it's just a random person on the internet who *does not justify* their own downvotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I got your questions right. So you want to match the whole string including the quotes, but you want to replace/extract it only the expression without the quotes, right?

You typically can use the regex `replace` functionality to *extract* just a part of the match.

This is the regex expression:

```
""?(.*?)""?
```

And this the replace expression:

```
$1
```

Comment: That's good... I changed my regex to `(?<DoubleQ>\"\"(.*?)\"\")|(?<SingleQ>\"(.*?)\")` (just removed the '?') which now works as expected creating two new capturing groups I can extract information from. Thanks for your help ;-)